# Does 'onDidChangeTextDocument()' promise in VScode extension depend on the user's active window to start listening?

Tags: javascript, vscode-extensions

I'm a new developer and this is my first Stack Overflow post. I've tried to stick to the format as best as possible. It's a difficult issue for me to explain, so please let me know if there's any problems with this post!

**Problem**
I'm working on a `vscode` extension specifically built for `Next.js` applications and running into issues on an event listener for the `onDidChangeText()` method. I'm looking to capture data from a JSON file that will always be located in the root of the project (this is automatically generated/updated on each refresh of the test node server for the Next.js app).

**Expected Results**
The extension is able to look for updates on the file using `onDidChangeText()`.  However, the issue I'm facing is on the initial run of the application. In order for the extension to start listening for changes to the JSON file, the user  has to be in the JSON file. It's supposed to work no matter what file the user has opened in `vscode`. After the user visits the JSON file while the extension is on, it begins to work from every file in the Next.js project folder.

Reproducing this issue is difficult because it requires an extension, `npm package`, and a `next.js` demo app, but the general steps are below. If needed, I can provide code for the rest.
1. Start debug session
2. Open Next.js application
3. Run application in node dev
4. Do not open the root JSON file

**What I've Tried**

- Console logs show we are not entering the `onDidTextDocumentChange()` block until the user opens the root JSON file.
- File path to the root folder is correctly generated at all times, and prior to the promise being reached.
- Is this potentially an `async` issue? Or is the method somehow dependent on the Active Window of the user to start looking for changes to that document?
- Since the file is both created and updated automatically, we've tested for both, and neither are working until the user opens the root JSON file in their `vscode`.

Relevant code snippet (this will not work alone but I can provide the rest of the code if necessary. ).

```js
export async function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    console.log('Congratulations, your extension "Next Step" is now active!');
    setupExtension();
    const output = vscode.window.createOutputChannel('METRICS');
    // this is getting the application's root folder filepath string from its uri
    if (!vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders) {
        return;
    }
    const rootFolderPath = vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders[0].uri.path;
    // const vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders: readonly vscode.WorkspaceFolder[] | undefined;
    // this gives us the fileName - we join the root folder URI with the file we are looking for, which is metrics.json
    const fileName = path.join(rootFolderPath, '/metrics.json');

    const generateMetrics = vscode.commands.registerCommand(
        'extension.generateMetrics',
        async () => {
            console.log('Succesfully entered registerCommand');
            toggle = true;
            vscode.workspace.onDidChangeTextDocument(async (e) => {
        
            if (toggle) {
                console.log('Succesfully entered onDidChangeTextDocument');
                if (e.document.uri.path === fileName) {
                // name the command to be called on any file in the application
               // this parses our fileName to an URI - we need to do this for when we run openTextDocument below
               const fileUri = vscode.Uri.parse(fileName);
               // open the file at the Uri path and get the text
               const metricData = await vscode.workspace
                   .openTextDocument(fileUri)
                   .then((document) => {
                       return document.getText();
                   });
               }
           }
       }); 
   });
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by adding an "openTextDocument" call inside the "registerCommand" block outside of the "onDidChangeTextDocument" function. This made the extension aware of the 'metrics.json' file without it being open in the user's IDE.